# Use the result of 'whoami' as part of an alias

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alias, bashrc

I am setting up my default `.bashrc` on my Ubuntu machine that I will soon be adding more and more users to.

One command that users will have access to is `mysql`, logging them into the SQL system on the server. Is there a was yo dynamically update the `.bashrc` depending on the username without human intervention?

What I am looking for is to set up an alias for the following:

User Matt will have an alias:

> alias sql='mysql -u matt -p'

User Jim will have an alias:

> alias sql='mysql -u jim -p'

The mysql username will always be the same as the system username, making me wonder if there was a simple way to get the output of `whoami` and use that as part of the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use /etc/skel and put a .bashrc inside with

```
alias sql='mysql -u `whoami` -p';
```

Comment: Why call the command `whoami` when you can use the `USER` environmental variable?

Comment: `` is deprecated. you may consider to use $(whoami) instead. Also there is no need for ; at the end. Just write everything in one line. A function might be more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

Use a **function** instead of abusing `alias`

```
sql() { mysql -u $USER -p "$@"; }
```

Add to `/etc/skel/.bashrc` for new users and `/etc/bash.bashrc` for existing users.